# Core calculus in scala type system (recursion)

Tags: scala

How does the Typer in the scala compiler verify the following:

```
class D[T <: D[T]]
class E extends D[E]
```

The upper bound D[T] of class D's type parameter must be compatible with E. Type E is not equivalent to D, so its base type D will be checked. Because the type constructors of E's base type and D are equal, the bounds must be checked. And here comes the recursion.
The [Core Calculus](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/mfcs06.pdf) does not handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Start with

```
E extends D[E]
```

2) Extends implies subtyping in Scala, so

```
E <: D[E]
```

3) Because of the definition "class D[T <: D[T]]", the requirement on T for any D[T] is that T <: D[T].  Step 2 said E must be able to be able to be plugged in to T, so it better match that requirement.  Substituting E for T we get the requirement that

```
E <: D[E]
```

We already showed E <: D[E] in step 2.  We're done.

Answer (score 3):

No real answer, just two remarks: This pattern is known as [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), and it works in Java, too (see `java.lang.Enum`)